# Save User input on a screen composable and in a room database using Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

My goal is to save data that the user inputs in a field ( my case outlinedtextfield ) and store that data both on screen for the user to see and in a local database using room. I have created the basics of room ( Database, Dao, Data class, Repository, RepositoryImpl and a viewmodel ), but I cant figure out how to save the user input into it/ take user input and save it to the database I created. I want to save both string input and Int input. How can I achieve this while following best practices with dependency injection ?

My current information:

Main Activity:
https://gyazo.com/163dfa890d4ac10c2bd28c7876f25b4a

Data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "student_table")
data class Student(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone_number") val phoneNumber: Int?

)
```

My Dao:

```
@Dao
interface StudentDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM student_table")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<Student>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(student: Student)

    @Update
    fun update(student: Student)

    @Delete
    fun delete(student: Student)

    @Delete
    fun deleteAll(student: Student)

}
```

My Database:

```
@Database(entities = [Student::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun studentDao() : StudentDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE : AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context) : AppDatabase {

            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {

                return tempInstance
            }

            synchronized(this) {

                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "app_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
interface StudentRepository {

    suspend fun getAllStudentsFromRoom(): Flow<List<Student>>

    suspend fun addStudent(student: Student)

    suspend fun updateStudent(student: Student)

    suspend fun deleteStudent(student: Student)
}
```

My Implementation Repository

```
class StudentRepositoryImpl(
        private val studentDao: StudentDao
) : StudentRepository {
    override suspend fun getAllStudentsFromRoom(): Flow<List<Student>> = studentDao.getAll()

    override suspend fun addStudent(student: Student) = studentDao.insert(student)

    override suspend fun updateStudent(student: Student) = studentDao.update(student)

    override suspend fun deleteStudent(student: Student) = studentDao.delete(student)

}
```

My ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class StudentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: StudentRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    fun addStudent(student: Student) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repo.addStudent(student)
    }

    fun updateStudent(student: Student) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repo.updateStudent(student)
    }

    fun deleteStudent(student: Student) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repo.deleteStudent(student)
    }


}
```

Comment: Take a look into my sample: https://github.com/nglauber/JetpackComposePlayground/tree/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/nglauber/jetpackcomposeplayground/crud

Comment: I downloaded the project, updated it but apparently some features has been depricated and no longer works with this build! https://gyazo.com/ace371a042a852b9e5cdb279ea19d69d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2022.08.16**

I managed to solve the problem. There was a few things missing that I needed to add in order for it to work.

1. I needed to attribute @AndroidEntryPoint on the mainActivity.
   [image]
2. I needed to create an application class for my project: https://gyazo.com/326ac277d951814cf77a255afa438794
3. After creating the application class, I had to "call it" in the Android manifest by adding it in the following format in the application:
   "**android:name=".application.MyDatabaseProjekt2022**"
   Like this:
   [image]
4. I also needed to create an appModule class, I did this by doing the following:
   https://gyazo.com/0fed4a454d56e696c08cd98f02c7c98f
5. I also took some information suggested by FishHawk and created a simple UI to display the information. *rememberSavable* is used to save user information on screen incase the user navigates away from that composable screen! This is the result:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import com.example.MyDatabaseProjekt2022.data.Student
import com.example.MyDatabaseProjekt2022.viewmodel.StudentViewModel

@Composable
fun Test() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<StudentViewModel>()
    Column {
        var id: Int by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
        var firstName by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        var lastName by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        var phoneNumber by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(value = firstName, onValueChange = { firstName = it },
            label = { Text(text = "First Name")},
            singleLine = true,
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(value = lastName, onValueChange = { lastName = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Last Name")},
            singleLine = true
            )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = phoneNumber,
            onValueChange = { phoneNumber = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Phone Number")},
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone),
            singleLine = true,
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Button(onClick = {
            val realPhoneNumber = phoneNumber
            val student = Student(id,firstName, lastName, realPhoneNumber)
            viewModel.addStudent(student)
        }) { Text(text = "Save Student") }
    }
}
```

6. In order to verify whether or not the information gets saved in the database, do the following. Run the app and go to: **View -> Tool windows -> App inspection**
7. Type in the information (firstname, lastname, phonenumber), press the save student button and database should show up like this:
   https://gyazo.com/b85766f0ffa4470036cf5d7c4dd9d9f7
8. Double tap **student_table** and another window next to that should pop up with the saved information that you put in.

Hopefully this is everything you need in order to make a functional and working database. This took me around 2 months to figure out ( I do programming as a hobby and Im still in the "early stage" ). Hopefully someone here will find it useful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, is something like this okay?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<StudentViewModel>()
    Column {
        var firstName by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        var lastName by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        var phoneNumber by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        TextField(value = firstName, onValueChange = { firstName = it })
        TextField(value = lastName, onValueChange = { lastName = it })
        TextField(
            value = phoneNumber,
            onValueChange = { phoneNumber = it },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone)
        )
        Button(onClick = {
            val realPhoneNumber = parsePhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            val student = Student(firstName, lastName, realPhoneNumber)
            viewModel.updateStudent(student)
        }) { Text(text = "Save Data") }
    }
}
```

If you care about best practices, I personally recommend the simple MVI, which is best for jetpack compose. [My project](https://github.com/FishHawk/lisu-android) may help.

Comment: Will check it out and see if it works but this is essentially what I want: 1. The user will input their information ( firstname, lastname, phonenumber) in the text field. When the user press save data, the information is saved in the fields so if the user navigates away to another screen and then back, the information is still there in the text fields for the user to see.  2. The information should at the same time be saved in a local database, inside room database when the user has pressed the save data button. Hope this clarified it!

Comment: also to note, the navigation happens within a drawer and this composable will represent the profile screen for the user.

Comment: Then I think this is working. As long as the screen is still inside the `BackStack`, it can save the user's input. In addition, I replaced hilt with koin some time ago, so I'm not sure  if this is how to get the viewModel in the latest version.

Comment: I tested it out but for some reason it crashes the app. I get this error: cannot create an instance of class com ( app name ), will look more into it tomorrow but not sure why it happens!

Comment: I managed to solve it! I posted the answer as well!